# Proof of reverse of unique homomorphic extension theorem

Tags: logic

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $\Sigma$-Algebra, $X$ a subset of $\mathbf{A}$, and assume that $[\mathbf{X}]$ = $\mathbf{A}$, that is, X generates $\mathbf{A}$.

Prove that if for every $\Sigma$-Algebra $\mathbf{B}$ and function $h : X \rightarrow \mathbf{B}$ there is a unique homomorphism $\hat{h} : \mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}$ extending $h$, then $\mathbf{A}$ is freely generated by $X$.

I start by trying to show that each function $f_{\mathbf{A}} : A^n \rightarrow A$ is injective, but I don't see why this must be the case. I suppose that $f_{\mathbf{A}}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f_{\mathbf{A}}(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ then suppose for the sake of contradiction that some $x_i \neq y_i$. Then I try to use the existence of a homomorphism to show a contradiction, but I fail. I also try to use the uniqueness of the homomorphism, but I also failed this route. I cannot find something that from this shows that some $\hat{h}$ is not unique, or is otherwise contradictory.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Sorry for that, I edited the question with my approach and where I am stuck. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I would recommend against reaching for indirect proof so easily. Constructive proofs, ones that don't use indirect proof, are generally more informative and intuitive, though they can sometimes be harder or impossible. (The information has to come from somewhere.) Instead, a direct proof would be to simply construct $\hat h$ explicitly, show that it is a homomorphism, and show that any other homomorphism satisfying the same constraints is equal to the one you construct. The construction will likely be far more helpful than the mere fact that this statement holds.